# JQuery bind event when CSS background-image is fully loaded

Tags: jquery, image, background, loaded

I would like to trigger an event after a background-image is FULLY loaded.
The image is made from a dynamic PHP script.

```
$("#box").css("background-image","url(image.php)");
```

maybe I can try to get the image in a invisible `<img>` and when the image load (.load())
set the background-image with the src of that invisible `<img>` ? not sure...

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use my jQuery plugin called [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) that would help with this...

```
$("#box").css("background-image", "url(image.php)").waitForImages({
   waitForAll: true,
   finished: function() {
       // Background image has loaded.
   }
});
```

Otherwise, to do it manually...

```
var image = 'image.php',

    img = $('<img />');

img.bind('load', function() {
     // Background image has loaded.
});

img.attr('src', image);

$('#box').css('background-image', 'url(' + image + ')');
```

Comment: do you know why I get this error: Error: $.isPlainObject is not a function? (note that image.php generate a new image each time we call it)

Comment: @pelelive Are you using < jQuery 1.4?

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#box img").load(function() {  
    //the image elements in #box are fully loaded.
});
```

Comment: It's a `background-image`, not an `img` element.